# Getting User ID after OAuth Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I'm trying to integrate OAuth registration/login into my ASP.NET MVC 4 site. I'm having trouble getting the user's ID and/or username after login though. For login, I have:

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));

if(result.IsSuccessful)
{
    if(OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
    {
        string username = User.Identity.Name;
        int userID = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
    }
}
```

Although OAuthWebSecurity.Login is successful (returns true), username is set to an empty string and userID is set to -1 (which means that no one is logged in). Can anyone help explain this discrepancy between the login function returning true but these two ways of determining current user say otherwise? Or perhaps show me a way of finding the UserId (corresponding to the UserProfile table) after OAuth login?

This login structure is mostly from the default membership code that is given when starting an MVC 4 internet application.

Comment: This happens because you're trying to access user information in the same action that you have logged in. User information will be there in the next action, but not in this one. Same thing happens with logging out. I don't know why exactly it works like this though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it depends on the identification provider that you are using. The username property and the specific keys that the identity provider sends can be retrieved like this:

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));

string username = result.UserName;
string name = result.ExtraData["name"];
```

You will want to store the data that the identity provider sends back in your database (could be phone number, name, etc...) and that is also where your UserID will be generated. More information (and a beginning setup guide) can be found here:

- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Comment: This is great, thank you. On a similar topic, do you know how to access the user's email address after authenticating with Google? (Google tells you that the site can access your email)

Comment: @Jordan I havn't tried, but other answers indicate the following might work for Google: email = result.ExtraData["email"];